poco active record compiler support BLOB sqlite data
Is BLOB data supported via arc?  I can store unsigned char data in an stl:string but it seems under the hood poco or sqlite doesn't like that when inserting a string with embedded nulls, which is expected.
I'm guessing I have to create my own function to do this similar to the following thread.
Bind data for BLOB in POCO framework using SQLite wrapper
Is there a better way to do this maybe via the AbstractBinder classes?  In general do we have to drop to the native sqlite layer to get this done versus using POCO library calls?
